# Android TextView display a string to three decimal places through double convertion from another class

Tags: android, string, textview, format, double

I cannot restrict the TextView to show only 3 decimals when I'm using a variable from another class. Here's the problem:

I have this TextView

```
        public static TextView pt_resultado;
```

However when I tried to use it to show the number inputted from another screen while converting from Double  restricting the decimals:

```
pt_resultado.setText(String.format("%.3f",(Double.toString(ActivityPopulacao.pt_resultado2))));
```

I get the following error:

```
 java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %f can't format java.lang.String arguments
```

Is there a way to show only three decimals, put without changing the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying inserting string as float.
You should do:

```
pt_resultado.setText(String.format("%.3f",Double.valueOf(ActivityPopulacao.pt_resultado2.getText().toString())))
```

You need to:

1. Retrieve String from TextView.
2. Convert String to Double/Float.
3. Format Double/Float value as String at 3 decimal places.

**I assumed that ActivityPopulacao.pt_resultado2 is also TextView!**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you convert to string and try to format it like it is a `Double`?  
The `format()` method expects a number to format.  
Since `ActivityPopulacao.pt_resultado2` is Double you should format the double value:

```
pt_resultado.setText(String.format("%.3f", ActivityPopulacao.pt_resultado2));
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you also understand why this is happening ill break it flow a bit.

```
double recievedNum = ActivityPopulacao.pt_resultado2;
String convertedNumAsString = String.format ("%.3f", recievedNum);

pt_resultado.setText(convertedNumAsString);
```

Can you see the mistake? Your using Double.toString(number) where its expecting a number. String.format takes in the double does formatting and converts to string for you.

Comment: May I ask why my answer was downvoted, Trying to improve my answers. Without more code posted I used the provided info. My answer is directly from the docs

Answer (score 0):

Defining TextView as a static view will cause memory leaks. Going forward, you can pass value from one activity to another using `Intent` - I presume you're using activity. Also, `getText().toString()` has already converted the input value to string. So you don't need that `Double.toString()` any more. Copy below code and paste it in the code that is responsible for starting the new activity.

```
Intent in = new Intent(ActivityPopulacao.this, NewActivity.class);
in.putExtra("key", pt_resultado2.getText().toString());
startActivity(in);
```

To receive the value, get the intent and request for the string in your NewActivity `onCreate()` method.

```
String newDouble = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
pt_resultado.setText(newString);
```

Note that `NewActivity` in the above snippet refers to the activity that needs the value.